# nginx have too many 499 or 504 status code for half one hour

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, fastcgi

I deploy one web server in linode, use nginx as the proxy server.I check the nginx log find too many 499  and 504 errors in the log for half one hour. The log:

```
186.178.211.41~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:41 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:41+00:00~GET /category/?format=json&device_uid=mzHPz5IlTnd35XsLIcM6RwwAil4=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~15.484~-~.
186.178.211.41~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:41 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:41+00:00~GET /hot_search_words/?format=json&device_id=mzHPz5IlTnd35XsLIcM6RwwAil4=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~15.491~-~.
92.244.224.127~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:44 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:44+00:00~GET /artists/ru-RU/hot/?format=json&device_id=trXB2a4sVjugB3g6400Ivf6JVq0=&language_code=ru-ru HTTP/1.1~499~0~file:///Applications/Install/92C003B2-2C7B-499E-8533-F580EF1E5FE8/Install/~NativeHost~3.772~-~.
178.207.247.88~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:44 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:44+00:00~GET /artists/ru-RU/hot/?format=json&device_id=p3O/TpqU7tPBrw4QJamBI91FuGo=&language_code=ru-ru HTTP/1.1~499~0~file:///Applications/Install/92C003B2-2C7B-499E-8533-F580EF1E5FE8/Install/~NativeHost~18.669~-~.
189.167.212.240~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:49 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:49+00:00~GET /search/soda%20sterio/?format=json&device_id=a7xk4UCiPSp52cla6hA8glcY/xc=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~file:///Applications/Install/92C003B2-2C7B-499E-8533-F580EF1E5FE8/Install/~NativeHost~33.372~-~.
187.127.153.104~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:49 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:49+00:00~GET /artists/pt-BR/hot/?format=json&device_id=nUHU4vR/N1zrqXZGtz3kEv44H40=&language_code=pt-br HTTP/1.1~499~0~file:///Applications/Install/92C003B2-2C7B-499E-8533-F580EF1E5FE8/Install/~NativeHost~2.788~-~.
178.207.247.88~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:51 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:51+00:00~GET /artists/ru-RU/hot/?format=json&device_id=p3O/TpqU7tPBrw4QJamBI91FuGo=&language_code=ru-ru HTTP/1.1~499~0~file:///Applications/Install/92C003B2-2C7B-499E-8533-F580EF1E5FE8/Install/~NativeHost~2.780~-~.
201.160.162.251~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:51 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:51+00:00~GET /category/?format=json&device_uid=3R9U1EC9t9OPyCG+xx587jawrA4=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~37.645~-~.
201.160.162.251~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:51 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:51+00:00~GET /hot_search_words/?format=json&device_id=3R9U1EC9t9OPyCG+xx587jawrA4=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~37.658~-~.
191.40.56.15~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:52 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:52+00:00~GET /download_search/Coldplay/?format=json&device_id=BstZoStXYr9n7dta3lH87LZ+JdQ=&language_code=pt-br HTTP/1.1~200~36502~-~NativeHost~60.150~0.151~.
179.176.171.88~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:53 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:53+00:00~GET /download_search/mc%20daleste/?format=json&device_id=khIXpv8FfabUN+rP3W1zryMuKTg=&language_code=pt-br HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~27.803~-~.
200.49.206.194~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:57 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:57+00:00~GET /hot_search_words/?format=json&device_id=LXpdPQFTQvlpsxQoFx7Wc8lu3Ig=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~44.730~-~.
200.49.206.196~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:57 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:57+00:00~GET /category/?format=json&device_uid=LXpdPQFTQvlpsxQoFx7Wc8lu3Ig=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~42.503~-~.
82.54.64.173~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:57 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:57+00:00~GET /search_song/Eminem/?format=json&device_id=93rtmqeKtFWwLKryT6oUs+1vxuc=&language_code=it-it HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~25.195~-~.
79.30.49.69~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:58 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:58+00:00~GET /category/11/?format=json&device_id=hy/IVVuDP3UIxg4r3ht7mHJ9ZTU=&language_code=it-it HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~25.384~-~.
31.22.48.80~-~23/Nov/2014:19:42:59 +0000~2014-11-23T19:42:59+00:00~GET /download_search/Iggy%20Azalea/?format=json&device_id=0HXsA4AwHsE+j9Bx0I6gtiLV63A=&language_code=it-it HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~38.689~-~.
186.16.172.168~-~23/Nov/2014:19:43:00 +0000~2014-11-23T19:43:00+00:00~GET /category/?format=json&device_uid=Fv+ux25HB4g+0u7ANpmEjSpN9U4=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~20.327~-~.
186.16.172.168~-~23/Nov/2014:19:43:00 +0000~2014-11-23T19:43:00+00:00~GET /hot_search_words/?format=json&device_id=Fv+ux25HB4g+0u7ANpmEjSpN9U4=&language_code=es-mx HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~20.317~-~.
83.149.35.184~-~23/Nov/2014:19:43:01 +0000~2014-11-23T19:43:01+00:00~GET /hot_search_words/?format=json&device_id=Srf/h9PjMl9IqO/RRW+R63f/fM4=&language_code=ru-ru HTTP/1.1~499~0~-~NativeHost~26.999~-~.
```

this is the nginx log at normal time:

> 99.20.177.137~-~24/Nov/2014:06:33:08 +0000~2014-11-24T06:33:08+00:00~GET /category/?format=json&device_uid=aMjSSmVjO89d+pCPIpDCDmcwhcU=&language_code=en-us
>   HTTP/1.1~200~1217~-~NativeHost~0.050~0.050~.
>   99.20.177.137~-~24/Nov/2014:06:33:08 +0000~2014-11-24T06:33:08+00:00~GET /hot_search_words/?format=json&device_id=aMjSSmVjO89d+pCPIpDCDmcwhcU=&language_code=en-us
>   HTTP/1.1~200~1036~-~NativeHost~0.049~0.049~.
>   213.119.140.83~-~24/Nov/2014:06:33:08 +0000~2014-11-24T06:33:08+00:00~GET /category/5/?format=json&device_id=FxDpCbvaAT3cm97imBFribqr4dI=&language_code=nl-nl
>   HTTP/1.1~200~3359~-~NativeHost~0.024~0.024~.
>   201.29.210.76~-~24/Nov/2014:06:33:11 +0000~2014-11-24T06:33:11+00:00~GET /category/?format=json&device_uid=9dcT9DnwXug7R4KHGZvC2PReGkg=&language_code=pt-br
>   HTTP/1.1~200~1217~-~NativeHost~0.008~0.008~.
>   201.29.210.76~-~24/Nov/2014:06:33:11 +0000~2014-11-24T06:33:11+00:00~GET /hot_search_words/?format=json&device_id=9dcT9DnwXug7R4KHGZvC2PReGkg=&language_code=pt-br
>   HTTP/1.1~200~1036~-~NativeHost~0.009~0.009~.
>   107.77.80.86~-~24/Nov/2014:06:33:12 +0000~2014-11-24T06:33:12+00:00~GET /download_search/Linkin%20Park/?format=json&device_id=8svpotKbUezqsRWIZrHER0IqEu8=&language_code=en-us
>   HTTP/1.1~200~32708~-~NativeHost~0.105~0.105~.
>   173.209.211.245~-~24/Nov/2014:06:33:12 +0000~2014-11-24T06:33:12+00:00~GET /download_search/tony%20toni%20tone%20just%20me%20and%20you/?format=json&device_id=wMvgYR5zUWlo8DuXdC6QjmMGAaY=&language_code=en-us
>   HTTP/1.1~200~39~-~NativeHost~0.122~0.122~.

I use the fastcgi as the python wsgi server. After a while, the web server be normal. 
I want to know why this happen and how to avoid this accident?

Comment: Speed up your backend. 499 means client don't want to wait for answer for so long time.

Comment: I know what 499 means. But after that time, all api works and response time is about 100ms.I want to know why this happen.

Comment: Well, obviously your backend was slow. Investigate it (I don't know what could cause slowness of python, Garbage collector, network errors, database errors, etc.)

Comment: I post the nginx log at normal time, I don't know why this different so much.

Comment: Nginx has nothing to do with it. It's just a proxy to your backend. So look for problem in your python app.